# QTableView: sort by header index -1

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I am using PyQt4 and have a `QTableView` with a 2 columns data.
There is an extra column for an index (it comes from the `headerData` function of the source model). For sorting when clicking on the header buttons I wrap my model with a proxy class.

That's working fine, but I also want to sort by the first column by clicking on the left-top corner button `(column number: "-1" I would say)`:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABkcJ.png]

As requested, here is a minimal example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import random, sys

class MyModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

  headers = 'Name', 'Value'

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent)

    # Dummy data
    rows = []
    columns = []    
    for i in range(10):
      numbr = random.randint(1,20)
      rows.append('Name #%i' % numbr)
      columns.append('Value #%i' % numbr)
    self.data = zip(rows, columns)

  def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    return 2

  def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
    return len(self.data)

  def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if not index.isValid():
      return None

    if (index.row() >= len(self.data)) or (index.row() < 0):
      return None

    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
      return self.data[index.row()][index.column()]

    return None

  def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole :
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal :
            return self.headers[section]
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical :
            return section
    return None

class MyProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
      super(MyProxyModel, self).__init__()

    def lessThan(self, left_index, right_index):
      left_var = left_index.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
      right_var = right_index.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

      # Column #1 (values) should be not sortable
      if left_index.column() == 1: 
        return False

      return left_var < right_var

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()     

    self.model = MyModel()

    self.proxy = MyProxyModel()
    self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
    self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(0)

    self.selectionModel = QtGui.QItemSelectionModel(self.proxy)

    self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView()
    self.tableView.setModel(self.proxy)    
    self.tableView.setSelectionModel(self.selectionModel)

    self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.tableView.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)    
    self.setCentralWidget(self.tableView) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = MainWindow()
  window.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must be able to get the `cornerWidget` which is a `QAbstractButton`, for that we use `findChild`. Then we use `sort(-1)` that invalidates the ordering and places it in the initial state.

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...    
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableView) 
        cornerButton = self.tableView.findChild(QtGui.QAbstractButton)
        cornerButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.proxy.sort(-1))
```

Comment: Thank you, this `self.proxy.sort(-1))` solution works perfectly and does exactly what it is supposed to: `invalidates the ordering and places it in the initial state`.
But in my case the vertical headers consists of a list of tool names. They may be renamed, so when they are sorted with a corner button, they may become not in alphabetic order due to their initial state. Of course, I could add another column to the main table body with the same names and sort from there. But is it possible to sort them alphabetically with corner button press? [Imgur](https://imgur.com/IT07TYB)