# QTableView: How to sort input data in TableView by row index (header index -1)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, qtablewidget

I am working with `QTableView`. I am able to sort the data based on individual column headers in both ascending as well as descending orders. Once I sort the data by column header, I would like to again sort it based on the original index. I tried following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555969/qtableview-sort-by-header-index-1) but was unable to fix it.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from qtpy import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from qtpy.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel
from qtpy.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView

data = np.random.random((10, 3))

app = QApplication([''])


class SimpleModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    headers = 'Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.order = np.arange(data.shape[0])
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return 10

    def columnCount(self, index=None):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            col = index.column()
            row = index.row()
            return str(data[self.order[row], col])

    def sort(self, column, ascending):
        self.order = np.argsort(data[:, column])
        if ascending == Qt.DescendingOrder:
            self.order = self.order[::-1]
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole :
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal :
                return self.headers[section]
            elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical :
                return section
        return None


table = QTableView()
table.setModel(SimpleModel())
table.show()

app.exec_()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: whats are `table_viewer` and `LayerArtist`?, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc I have updated the code to provide a MCVE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the sort method orders the data and that transformation is irreversible, the previous solution uses a proxy, this orders the visual part but not the data, so in the end in the case of the other solution it is enough to avoid reordering and show the original data.

```
import numpy as np
from qtpy import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

data = np.random.random((10, 3))*10 -9

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([''])


class SimpleModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    headers = 'Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.order = np.arange(data.shape[0])
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return 10

    def columnCount(self, index=None):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            col = index.column()
            row = index.row()
            return str(data[self.order[row], col])

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole :
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal :
                return self.headers[section]
            elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical :
                return section
        return None

class SortProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def lessThan(self, left_index, right_index):
        left_var = self.sourceModel().data(left_index)
        right_var = self.sourceModel().data(right_index)
        return float(left_var) < float(right_var)


table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
model = SimpleModel()
proxy = SortProxyModel()
proxy.setSourceModel(model)
table.setModel(proxy)
table.show()
cornerButton = table.findChild(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton)
cornerButton.clicked.connect(lambda: proxy.sort(-1))
app.exec_()
```